# What is the correct query for nested relationship records in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I have a search result page to show the builders in a specific city. City is selected by a dropdown. I need to show the builder records with total projects in that city and total listings in that city.

A builder can have many projects and a project can have many listings. A city can have many projects.

My blade is :

```
@php
    $totalprojects = App\Models\projects::whereHas('city', function ($query) 
                                    {$query->where('status', 1);})
                                    ->where('project_builder',$item->id)
                                    ->count();
    $totallistings = App\Models\Listings::whereHas('project.builder', function ($query) 
                                    use ($item) {$query->where('id',$item->id);})->count();
@endphp
```

This code is working fine to show the correct number of builders , but showing incorrect number of projects and listings of a builder.

My controller is

```
 public function SearchBuildersincity(Request $request){

        $city = $request->project_city;

        $builders = Builders::whereHas('project', fn ($query) =>
        $query->when($request->project_city, fn ($query, $city) => $query->where('project_city', $city))
            ->whereHas('city', fn ($query) => $query->where('status', 1)))
        ->latest()
        ->paginate(10)
        ->withQueryString();

        $builderscount = Builders::whereHas('project', fn ($query) =>
        $query->when($request->project_city, fn ($query, $city) => $query->where('project_city', $city))
            ->whereHas('city', fn ($query) => $query->where('status', 1))
        )
        ->count();

        $cities = Cities::where('status', 1)->orderBy('city_name','ASC')->latest()->get();

        return view('frontend.builder.searchbuilders',compact('builderscount','builders', 'cities'));

    } // end method
```

What is the correct query ?